# Counting number of sorted subgroups inpostgresql

Tags: sql, postgresql

I would like to count the number of sorted subgroups  in the table below :

```
id  nmb
1   11
2   12
3   13
4   22
5   23
6   31
7   32
8   33
9   11
10  12
11  13
12  12
13  13
14  21
15  22
16  11
17  12
18  13
19  14
```

And want to obtain something like this in postgresql 8.4 :

```
id  nmb local  
1   11  1  
2   12  1  
3   13  1  
4   22  1  
5   23  1  
6   31  1  
7   32  1  
8   33  1  
9   11  2  
10  12  2  
11  13  2  
12  12  3  
13  13  3  
14  21  3  
15  22  3  
16  11  4  
17  12  4  
18  13  4  
19  14  4
```

EDIT: the last few numbers on the  'local' column were wrong. Corrected!

Thank you.

Comment: Can you explain the rules for creating those numbers? I don't get it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It appears that you are trying to enumerate the groups, where a group starts with a lower `nmb` value than the previous row ("previous" defined by the `id` order).

The idea is to identify the start of a group by using `lag()`.  Then take the cumulative sum to get the group identifier that you want:

```
select id, nmb, sum(StartFlag) over (order by id) as local
from (select id, nmb,
             lag(nmb) over (order by id) as lastnmb,
             (case when lag(nmb) over (order by id) < nmb then 0
                   else 1
              end) as StartFlag
      from t
     ) t
order by id;
```

Answer (score 2):

I though i finally understood what you want, consecutively growing values:

```
select id, nmb,
   sum(flag)
   over (order by id
         rows unbounded preceding) as local
from
 (
   select
      id, nmb,
      case
        when lag(nmb) 
             over (order by id) < nmb
          then 0 
        else 1
      end as flag
   from t
 ) as dt
order by id
```

But group 4 doesn't fit

Edit: Now they fit :-)

Answer (score 1):

[SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!11/1acc8/2)

```
select
    id, nmb,
    row_number() over(partition by nmb order by id)
from t
order by id
```

Comment: Those last few numbers are way off.

Comment: @GigaWatt Your expected result is wrong. Check it. Or explain the logic.